# App Crashes when start for first time because of breakpoints in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

When i run my project on xcode, then first time it goes to autorelease pool (i.e main) method. And then by clicking "step over" button it starts and works fine. What is the reason for this. It only happens when i add breakpoints, otherwise app works fine.

Comment: You have turned on `Exceptional Breakpoints`, If you disable breakpoints then it won't pause the application.

Comment: Its not crashing just stop at exceptions you can continue from play button at bottom

Comment: I know it is because of exceptional breakpoints, but what is the reason of stopping the app at that position even if we dont have exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete or Disable `All Exceptions` Breakpoints.

To remove or disable `Exceptional Breakpoints` goto breakpoint list, right click on `All Exceptions` breakpoints and then select `Disable Breakpoint` or `Delete BreakPoint` option.

[image]